# Angular initilization variables (Arrays, objects) undefined at ngOnInit || Received Json Object, no accecible attributs of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm facing an issue with Angular 9 while executing my component pdfMaker, the title explain my issue, other whise , when i'm instanciate my variables (arrays ans objects before affectation) and after NgInit thoes are empty(undefined) in HTML and console.log. The problem is the same when i'm using rxjs to observe JSON result into variables, in fact the variables are affected, but attributes are not defined.

Here is my component PDFMaker (HTML,TS) and my service.ts :

pdfmaker.html

```
<body class="body">
<div id="content" #content>
  <p>{{helpdesk}}</p>
  <table class="table-striped BORDERED">
   <thead>
   <tr>
     <td>Article</td>
     <td>Quantité</td>
     <td>Prix Unitaire HT</td>
     <td>Prix Unitaire ttc</td>
     <td>Article Originel</td>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   <tr>
     <td><p><input type="text"  name="designation" placeholder="Designation"  [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[0].AD_designation" #model_article="ngModel"></p></td>
     <td><p><input type="number" name="quantity"                              [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[0].AD_quantity"></p></td>
     <td><p><input type="text"   name="prix_ht"     placeholder="prix ht"     [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[0].AD_prix_ht"></p></td>
     <td><p><input type="text"   name="prix_ttc"    placeholder="prix_ttc"    [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[0].AD_prix_ttc"></p></td>
     <td>
       <select name="article_original"
               id="article_original1"
               class="form-control"
       >
         <option  [value]="0" style="color:white;background-color:red;">
           Ne pas affecter pour le moment
         </option>
         <option *ngFor="let AO of AL_article_original" [value]="AO?.AO_id">
           {{AO?.AO_designation}}
         </option>
       </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let mf of model_for">
      <span class="ligne{{mf}}" style="display:none;">
        <td><p><input type="text"  name="designation"  placeholder="Designation" [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[mf].AD_designation"></p></td>
        <td><p><input type="number"  name="quantity"  [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[mf].AD_quantity"></p></td>
        <td><p><input type="text" name="prix_ht"  placeholder="prix ht" [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[mf].AD_prix_ht"></p></td>
        <td><p><input type="text" name="prix_ttc" placeholder="prix_ttc"  [(ngModel)]="model_article_devis[mf].AD_prix_ttc"></p></td>
        <td>
        <select name="article_original"
                id="article_original"
                class="form-control inputfield"
                >
                                  <option  [value]="0" style="color:white;background-color:red;">
                                    Ne pas affecter pour le moment
                                  </option>
                                  <option  *ngFor="let AO of AL_article_original" [value]="AO.AO_id">
                                    {{AO.AO_designation}}
                                  </option>
                                </select>
        </td>
      </span>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<button (click)="Add_ligne()">Ajouter une ligne</button>
<button (click)="Del_ligne()">Supprimer une ligne</button>
<button (click)="GenererPDF()">Fk</button>
</body>
```

pdfmaker.ts

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import {Devis} from '../models/devis';
import {Article_devis} from '../models/article_devis';
import * as $ from 'Jquery';
import {Article_origine} from '../models/article_origine';
import {ArticleOrigineService} from '../shares/services/devis/article-origine.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pdfmake',
  templateUrl: './pdfmake.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pdfmake.component.scss']
})
export class PdfmakeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
   helpdesk  = "helpdesk";
   model_devis : Devis = { DEV_id: null, DEV_total_TTC: null, DEV_total_HT: null, DEV_ref: null, DEV_note: null, DEV_id_part: null, DEV_id_article_devis: null, DEV_etat: null, DEV_date: null };
   model_article_devis : Article_devis[] =  [null];
   model_for : number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30];
   count_ligne = 1;
   AL_article_original : Article_origine[] = [null];
  constructor(private ArticleOrigineService: ArticleOrigineService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.model_for.length-1; i++){
    //  this.model_article_devis[i] =  { AD_remise: null, AD_prix_ttc: null, AD_id_AO: null, AD_id: null, AD_quantity: null, AD_prix_ht: null, AD_id_Devis: null, AD_designation: null};
      this.AL_article_original[i] = { AO_designation: "ok", AO_id: 1, AO_stock: null, AO_remise: null, AO_prix_ttc: null, AO_prix_ht: null};
    }
    this.getAllArticle_Origine();
  }

  getAllArticle_Origine(){
    this.ArticleOrigineService.GET_ALL_ARTICLE_ORIGINE().subscribe(
      success => {
        this.AL_article_original = success;
        for(let i=0; i < this.AL_article_original.length; i++){
            console.log(this.AL_article_original[i]?.AO_designation);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error while getting the Originals Articles");
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
  Add_ligne(){
    if(this.count_ligne === 1 ){
      let x = $(".ligne1");
      x.show();
      this.count_ligne = 2;
    }else if(this.count_ligne === 2 ){
      let x = $(".ligne2");
      x.show();
      this.count_ligne = 3;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 3 ){
      let x = $(".ligne3");
      x.show();
      this.count_ligne = 4;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 4 ){
      let x = $(".ligne4");
      x.show();
      this.count_ligne = 5;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 5 ){
      let x = $(".ligne5");
      x.show();
      this.count_ligne = 6;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 6 ){
      let x = $(".ligne6");
      x.show();
      this.count_ligne = 7;
    }
  }
  Del_ligne(){
    if(this.count_ligne === 2 ){
      let x = $(".ligne1");
      x.hide();
      this.count_ligne = 1;
    }else if(this.count_ligne === 3 ){
      let x = $(".ligne2");
      x.hide();
      this.count_ligne = 2;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 4 ){
      let x = $(".ligne3");
      x.hide();
      this.count_ligne = 3;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 5 ){
      let x = $(".ligne4");
      x.hide();
      this.count_ligne = 4;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 6 ){
      let x = $(".ligne5");
      x.hide();
      this.count_ligne = 5;
    }
    else if(this.count_ligne === 7 ){
      let x = $(".ligne6");
      x.hide();
      this.count_ligne = 6;
    }
  }
  GenererPDF() {
      const doc = new jsPDF();

      const specialElementHandlers = {
        '#content' : function(element, renderer) {
          return true;
        }
      };

      const content = this.content.nativeElement;

      doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
        width: 190,
        elementHandlers : specialElementHandlers
      });

      doc.save('test.pdf');
  }
}
```

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../../../environments/environment.prod';
import {Article_origine} from '../../../models/article_origine';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleOrigineService {
  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  AO_URL  = `${this.baseUrl}WEB_ARTICLE_ORIGINE/`;
  ADD_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL = this.AO_URL+"ADD_ARTICLE_ORIGINE";
  GET_ONE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL = this.AO_URL+"GET_ONE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE";
  GET_ALL_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL = this.AO_URL+"GET_ALL_ARTICLE_ORIGINE";
  DELETE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL = this.AO_URL+"DELETE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  ADD_ARTICLE_ORIGINE(ArticleOrigine: Article_origine): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.ADD_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL, ArticleOrigine);
  }
  GET_ONE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.GET_ONE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL + id);
  }
  GET_ALL_ARTICLE_ORIGINE(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.GET_ALL_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL);
  }
  DELETE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.DELETE_ARTICLE_ORIGINE_URL + id);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest editing the code so it can be read with inducing eye bleed.

Comment: I did, its better to read now ?